# Is it possible to store 8 characters (1-byte each) in a variable of type double (8-bytes) in c/c++?

Tags: c++, c, char, multilingual

I am migrating some legacy Fortran77 code to C/C++. In the Fortran77 code, if 8 characters are read in from a file, they can be stored in a variable of type real*8 without a problem.

Is it possible to do a similar thing in C or C++? If so, how would I do it? I haven't been able to find any solutions on the internet. I need to read in 8 characters using C/C++ and store them in a variable of type double, which is then passed back to Fortran and corresponds to the original real*8 variable.

Many thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT:**
In response to @sixlettervariables, I'll just clarify my use-case a bit more. The issue I have with his suggestion is that I only know the format of each line (i.e. which fields are strings, which numbers) at runtime, and hence I can't know what members the struct should have statically. The fields also need to occupy a contiguous block of memory in the order they are read in.

Concretely, in one run of the program the format of each line might be: **f1:string, f2:number, f3:number, f4:string**, but in another **f1:string, f2:string, f3:string, f4:number, f5:number**.  For the first case I'd need:

```
struct { char[8] f1; double f2; double f3; char[8] f4}
```

For the second I'd need:

```
struct { char[8] f1; char[8] f2; char[8] f3; double f4; double f5}
```

Perhaps there is some way to do this with templates?

Comment: Have you tried standard library function for this.check below link http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atof/

Comment: It might cause problems. Some combination of bits have a specific interpretation as a double on many systems such as NaN or infinity. If you hit one of those you might not get your original bits back, or might get exceptions etc. Although I'd expect fortran to have the same kind of issues too...

Comment: you can sure store them that way, but the bits could be laid out differently... I would want to test a whole bunch of conditions... epsilon, min, max  -  special bits: nan, inf, sign, neg inf... etc.

Answer (score 6):

You do not need to store them in a `double` just because Fortran needed to do that. In fact, you absolutely *should not* do that in your C/C++ code.

Simply store the character data in a character array.

If you're mixing Fortran and C/C++, the two have no idea about one another outside of their ABI. From the C side you can simply *claim* that the Fortran interface takes a character array, when in fact it is expecting an array of doubles. And the same is true from the Fortran side.

From the C side:

```
extern void FCHARS(char* str, int length);

/* ... */
int flength = 0; /* optional: length of the string in Fortran terms */
char str[9]; /* in C/C++ add one for \0 at the end */

/* read in up to a block of 8 */
fgets(str, sizeof(str), fp);

/* At this point if you know the 8 characters are space padded to their end
 * you have no more work to do, otherwise you may need to fill from the right
 * with spaces.
 */
{
    size_t ii = sizeof(str) - 1;
    while (ii > 0 && str[ii - 1] == '\0') {
        str[ii - 1] = ' ';
        flength = ii--;    /* optional: keep track of our unpadded length */
    }
}

/* Once you've space padded the string you can call your Fortran method.
 * If your Fortran method accepts a string of unknown length, supply
 * `flength`. If your Fortran method expects a string of a fixed length, pass
 * the size of `str` (excluding '\0') instead.
 */
FCHARS(str, flength);
```

As long as you follow the ABI requirements of your Fortran compiler (e.g. CDECL, hidden string lengths passed interleaved) from the C/C++ code, you'll be fine.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. My problem is that I am expecting to read in a mixture of characters (maximum 8) and real numbers from the input file and want to save them in the same array in C/C++ - as is done in the old fortran code. I therefore need to have an array of doubles in both fortran and c, and was trying to avoid having to involve a character array in c as well.

Comment: You do not *actually* want to do that. C/C++ afford you a wealth of options that older Fortran does not, and in this case `struct`. So if your data is structured in any fashion, you should use a `struct` instead. I guarantee 110% that you do not actually need to store characters in `double`s, mostly because it isn't necessary.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I ran out of space in my reply so please see my edit to the post above if you've time! Best.

Comment: @marigold260: is this file binary or fixed width text?

Comment: And the Fortran expects fixed width text or the actual data?

Comment: The Fortran just wants the data (in its real array). I am trying to make the C code do all the reading in from files and parsing.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just use a cast.  You might want to add a static_assert for safety:

```
double d;
char * b = (char*)&d;
static_assert(sizeof(d) == sizeof(char[8]), "Double must be large enough to hold 8 chars");
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this does replicate what happened in fortran, except I needed the character to be stored in a double variable so I just changed the casts around to `double* doublePtr; string s = "london"; doublePtr = (double*)(s.c_str());` ...with an assert. Is this what you would have done?

Answer (score 1):

```
union Data{
    char c[8];
    double d;
};
```

Save the 8 characters into `c`, and read it by `d`. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
// #include <stdlib.h>
union Data{
    char c[8];
    double d;
};

int main(){
    int i;
    union Data data;
    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        scanf("%hhd", data.c + i);
    printf("%e\n", data.d);
    // system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's invoking Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Why? I cannot find undefined behavior.

Comment: "Each entry in the argument list (for scanf) must be a pointer to a variable of a type that matches the corresponding conversion specification in format-string. If the types do not match, the results are undefined."

Comment: @jsn Why don't all of you just tell me that I used a wrong format? I kept thinking that I used union incorrectly. Anyway, I corrected my answer.

Comment: @johnchen902, why so sour so early in the morning?

Comment: @jsn Sorry, look at [my profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2040040/johnchen902), I live in Taiwan (UTC+08:00). It's 10:52pm now.

Comment: @johnchen902, well, it's morning here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29676/discussion-between-johnchen902-and-jsn)

Comment: @jsn I'm so curious that I clicked "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" But I think I had better go to sleep now.

Comment: Reading from union member other than last assigned is also an UB.

Comment: To be fair, while according to the standard this is UB, in most compilers I've seen & used, this will act just as you'd expect - a char array as it's double representation (and vice versa). If someone can come up with a compiler that does something completely unexpected when this code is used, then please, correct me.

Answer (score 0):

method 1

```
double a;
char ch;
int i;
for(i=0;i<8;i++)
{
   scanf("%c", &ch);
   a=a+ch;
   if(i!=8)
     a<<8; //left shifts by 8 bits, to accomodate another 8 bits on right.
}
```

method 2

```
double a
char *ch;
int i;
ch=&a;
for(i=0;i<8;i++)
{
   scanf("%c", ch);
   ch++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if it would be possible in C to store several chars and real numbers in a DOUBLE variable because C DOUBLE is equal to REAL*8 because both are double precision float numbers I would strongly advise against it.

This "trick" to store several chars and reals in REAL*8 feels like a hack to save space. I don't think this is needed nowadays and I do not think this "trick" would generate faster code. I would advise to use a UNION as mentioned above.

You could post the FORTAN code which reads the chars and reals into the REAL*8 this would make it easier to help you. And I must say I am intrigued to find out how this is done.

Comment: Well it wasn't a trick to save space back then as much as it was a requirement prior to the existence of the `CHARACTER` data type.

Comment: Yes, the code is from a time before the CHARACTER type existed. It is possible simply by providing a READ function with the appropriate format specifier for characters e.g. `CHARACTER*4 formatspec = '(A8)', REAL*8 input, READ(unit_no, formatspec) input`, where the file associated with unit_no contains a sequence of 8 characters.